# Read Large data from MongoDB and display in Graphs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, large-data

I have currently around 100,000 documents in mongoDB. This data contain set of data-points which I want to visualize in graphs using Node.js on the browser. Currently, when I try to read all the data I get the error "out of heap memory". I am using chart.js to represent it.

I was able to visualize around 10K records but those are also too slow.

Any suggestions how this can be done efficiently in Node.js

Comment: Can you filter the data to obtain only what you need for display? Can you accept lower-resolution display (e.g. 100 datapoints vs. 100k) which can be zoomed in?

Comment: Actually I need all the datapoints to be represented on the graph but may be I can try keeping 10K. Maybe that would be a good idea, do you know how that can be done? showing only 100 points and then based upon zoom make addition api call ?

Comment: Even if you want all the points, there may be extra data in those 100k documents that you could prune, e.g. dynamically filter on the way out. There are many options for zoom-able charts. A library like http://c3js.org/ or https://www.zingchart.com/ could help.

Comment: Actually I just save only the required datapoints no extra fields in that data.  Thanks i will try that library!